The amount of Ubuntu mirror space?
I followed the tutorial at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror to set up an Ubuntu mirror. In the tutorial, the required space is approximately mentioned as 1TB, but so far, it has filled up 3TB. I want to know how much space I need to have in total to make sure it's enough?

The value will of course keep changing. Use apt-mirror to get a reasonably precise value
